# What's wrong with map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    map<char*, int> m;
    int N;
    scanf ("%d", &N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        char name[256], s[256];
        scanf ("%s", &name);
        gets (s);
        m[name]++;
    }
    map<char*, int>::iterator itr;
    for (itr = m.begin(); itr != m.end(); itr++)
        printf ("%s %d", itr->first, (itr)->second);


}
```

This program meant to read number of lines then lines, and then output the number of times each word has been repeated in start of lines

for example with this input:

```
3
Spain Donna Elvira
England Jane Doe
Spain Donna Anna
```

I expect :

```
England 1
Spain 2
```

but I receive :

```
Spain 3
```

and I'm sure the the variable name is what it should be each time but something is wrong with the map.

my build log when I changed it to std::string

```
1>------ Build started: Project: UVa, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  UVa.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstddef(180): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xtree(2245) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstddef(179) : while compiling class template member function 'bool std::less<_Ty>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\map(194) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool std::less<_Ty>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\type_traits(743) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::less<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xtree(1028) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::is_empty<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::less<std::string>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\map(67) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<_Traits>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,int,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,int>>,false>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\amiraz\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\uva\uva\uva.cpp(13) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string,
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xtree(2245) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xtree(2245) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xtree(2245) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstddef(180): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(1983) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(1983) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(1983) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(1983) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstddef(180): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(1259) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(1259) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(1259) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(1259) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstddef(180): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(1075) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(1075) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(1075) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(1075) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstddef(180): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const std::string'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\utility(232) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\utility(232) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\utility(232) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\utility(232) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstddef(180): error C2676: binary '<' : 'const std::string' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Please don't mix C and C++.

Comment: Never use `gets`; it is fundamentally insecure.

Comment: You **may** be getting those errors after you change `char*` to `std::string` because you are passing `name` (which is a `char[]`) to `std::map<std::string, int>::operator [](std::string)`, which as you can see doesn't take a character pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you map with a `char*` as a key, you're really mapping the with the *address* of the string, not the string itself as a key. Since your buffer is identically allocated on the stack every time, it will most likely end up at the same address and map to the same value, no matter the content.

Mapping from std::string, the C++ alternative to C strings, will instead automatically use the *content* of the string as a key.

Answer (score 5):

`char*` are compared as pointers, not as strings. Use `std::string` instead.

And as P0W mentioned,`scanf`, `printf`, `gets` are C-style. Maps and iterators are C++-style. Don't mix them. Use `std::cin`, `std::cout`, `std::getline` for IO in C++.

Comment: In fact, don't mix `gets` with anything.

Comment: @md5: Except perhaps a blender

Comment: I'd +1 if you didn't blatantly say "don't use `printf`". That's more of a preference than anything when it comes to compile time known output strings.

Comment: this is my build log after I changed it to std::string

Comment: @CoffeeandCode You're talking about advanced topics, like performance. I doubt OP is qualified enough for these. So simple advices are the best.

Comment: You are implying that `scanf`, `printf` etc are not C++, which is wrong. These are still perfectly valid in C++.

Comment: @davmac what you said, and there are actually variants of `printf` that are c++ only!

Comment: @davmac Most of C code is a valid C++ code. I was talking about C++ style. Am I wrong that `printf` is a C-style, while `std::cout` is C++-style?

Comment: @Mikhail you say that "scanf, printf, gets are C." - not "scanf, printf, gets are C style." I wouldn't argue that these functions are "C++ style", but I think what you really mean is that using these functions is an antiquated idiom, which I fully accept. It's not about C vs C++.